# readAllLines Charset in Java

Tags: java

Update: Thanks for the quick responses, everyone. I've resolved the Charset issue, but now something else is happening that I don't understand at all. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
public class readConvertSeq{
    private static String[] getFile(Path file){
        String[] fileArray = (String[])Files.readAllLines(file, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII).toArray();
        return fileArray;
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] test = readConvertSeq.getFile(Paths.get(args[0]));
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
            System.out.println(test[i]);
        }   
    }   
}
```

And here's the error:

```
readConvertSeq.java:6: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    String[] fileArray = (String[])Files.readAllLines(file, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII).toArray();
```

I'm just trying to get an array of strings from a file, and I'm getting really frustrated by Java's pedantry. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
public class readConvertSeq{
    private static String[] getFile(Path file){
        String[] fileArray = Files.readAllLines(file, Charset("US-ASCII")).toArray();
        return fileArray;
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] test = readConvertSeq.getFile(Paths.get(args[0]));
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
            System.out.println(test[i]);
        }   
    }   
}
```

It gives me this:

```
readConvertSeq.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    String[] fileArray = Files.readAllLines(file, Charset("US-ASCII")).toArray();
                                                  ^
  symbol:   method Charset(String)
  location: class readConvertSeq
```

I'm sure I've made some other mistakes as well, so feel free to give me any advice you can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Charset is an abstract class therefore you cannot instantiate it with the **new** keyword.

To get a charset in Java 1.7 use `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`

Comment: +1 for using predefined constants (I somehow missed your `(because it uses a String parameter)` that's why I asked, I should have though of myself though)

Answer (score 5):

Constructors in Java are called with the `new` operator, so `Charset("US-ASCII")` is not a valid statement.
Moreover, `Charset`'s constructor is protected, so you'll have to use the static factory method to create it: `Charset.forName("US-ASCII")`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the below changes

```
String[] fileArray = (String[]) Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), Charset.forName("US-ASCII")).toArray();
                     ^^^^^ - Cast required                        ^^^^ - Get Charset using forName
```

See the docs of [`Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Comment: actually his "file" variable is of type Path so he doesn't need to use .toPath :-) Also as I mentioned in other comment forName(String) isn't recommended in Java7 for standard charsets.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk - Thanks. I somehow missed seeing it. `file` name for a `Path` object, is not digestable :D

Answer (score 2):

[Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) does not have a public constructor so you have to use the static factory method [Charset#forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: this can be error prone (because it uses a String parameter) so the guys at Oracle added a new class StandardCharsets  in Java7 containing constants for the common charsets for this kind of things.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk can you please give an error scenario? It is not even deprecated in `jdk7` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Arrays.html)). But indeed if there are some predefined constants available those should be used! **Edit** Yes because of string parameter, you could pass any thing, but the method seems to handle that with the principle s**t in s**t out ;-)

Comment: a simple typo will do Charset.forName("US-ASCI") :-) Apparently the problem was real since even before JDK7 Google Guava had a similar class Charsets with the same constants. Ah and forName() isn't deprecated because it's still useful! As the name states the JDK7 class is only for standard charsets :-) For others you still have to use forName().